# Angular 8 Async pipe high memory usage and crashes chrome

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have been having trouble using the async pipe in angular with firebase after the angular 8 release. I am not sure why this is and it is really bugging me.

I have my categories service:

```
    public getAllCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
    return this.afs.collection<Category>(`categories`).valueChanges();
  }
```

Then I have my component that uses the service like so:

```
    export class AttributesComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  count = 0;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private attributesService: AttributesService,
    public categoryService: CategoryService
  ) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      attributeArray: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }......etc......
```

and finally in my HTML I have my async pipe calling the public categoryService and the function:

```
{{ categoryService.getAllCategories() | async | json }}
```

I don't see why this shouldn't work, the service is returning the correct observable and the async should display it. There is no error gives, chrome just starts using Gigs of memory my computer's fans crank up, and I am forced to kill chrome.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong???

Thank a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that is because of you are calling `getAllCategories()` from view itself,

that causes to **returning continuous Observable** which is hard to handle for any browser... ;)
consider call the service method in **`Component`** then in the view

```
allCatageries :any;

...
ngOnInit() {
   this.allCatageries = categoryService.getAllCategories();
}
...
```

then in the **view**

```
{{ allCatageries  | async | json }}
```

hope this helps... :)